# How do I execute this query using the aggregation framework in MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I am trying to return the `visits` with `minute` greater than 12.

My data structure looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : "20120723/foobar/song/custom-cred",
  "live_daily_count" : 4,
  "metacontent" : { "date" : "20120723",
    "live_daily_statable_slug" : "custom-cred",
    "live_daily_statable_title" : "custom cred",
    "live_daily_statable_type" : "Song",
    "url" : "foobar/songs/custom-cred",
    "user_slug" : "foobar" },
  "visits" : [
    { "country_name" : "UK",
      "iso_two_letter_country_code" : "UK",
      "referer" : "http://localhost:3000/foobar/songs/no-title-with-space",
      "minute" : 12,
      "token_id" : "134300236111rcbmbmvv" },
    { "country_name" : "UK",
      "iso_two_letter_country_code" : "UK",
      "referer" : "http://localhost:3000/foobar/songs/no-title-with-space",
      "minute" : 13,
      "token_id" : "134300242111pjvkjjkf" },
    { "country_name" : "UK",
      "iso_two_letter_country_code" : "UK",
      "referer" : "http://localhost:3000/foobar/songs/no-title-with-space",
      "minute" : 13,
      "token_id" : "134300243511udbnqldm" }
  ]
}
```

I'm using the Mongodb Ruby driver. I tried with the following:

```
conn = Mongo::Connection.new
db   = conn['foobar_development']
cmd = {
  aggregate: 'live_daily_stats',
  pipeline: [
    { '$match' => { :_id => "20120723/foobar/song/custom-cred" } },
    { '$project' => {
      :visits => 1,
    } },
    { '$unwind' => '$visits' },
    # { '$group' => {
    #   :_id => '$_id'
    # } },
  ]
}

res = db.command(cmd)['result']
```

It now returns:

```
[
    [0] {
           "_id" => "20120723/foobar/song/custom-cred",
        "visits" => {
                                          "country_name" => "UK",
                           "iso_two_letter_country_code" => "UK",
                                               "referer" => "http://localhost:3000/foobar/songs/custom-cred",
                                                "minute" => 12,
                                              "token_id" => "134300236111rcbmbmvv"
        }
    },
    [1] {
           "_id" => "20120723/foobar/song/custom-cred",
        "visits" => {
                                          "country_name" => "UK",
                           "iso_two_letter_country_code" => "UK",
                                        "follower_class" => "non_follower",
                                               "referer" => "http://localhost:3000/foobar/songs/custom-cred",
                                                "minute" => 13,
                                              "token_id" => "134300242111pjvkjjkf"
        }
    },
    [2] {
           "_id" => "20120723/foobar/song/custom-cred",
        "visits" => {
                                          "country_name" => "UK",
                           "iso_two_letter_country_code" => "UK",
                                        "follower_class" => "non_follower",
                                               "referer" => "http://localhost:3000/foobar/songs/custom-cred",
                                                "minute" => 13,
                                              "token_id" => "134300243511udbnqldm"
        }
    }
]
```

How do I make sure the results only return the `visits` with `minute` greater than 12? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you want to $unwind the field $visits (what is $data?). And I think $unwind only works on arrays (which your visits are not).

Comment: See my edit, on `$unwind`. Still the same result `[]`. Second, should I change my data structure so that it uses arrays instead of hashes? Any way to get this to work with hashes instead of arrays? There is no particular reason why I use hashes. Just a personal preference

Comment: Have you considered using a separate collections for the visit log? That would make this particular query trivial (of course, we don't know your other queries).

Comment: Separate collections as in like a referenced or embedded document?

Comment: referenced, not embedded, yes. Every entry in "visits" would have the parent document's id in it. This removes the limit on the maximum number of visits you can store per document, and makes updates much faster, too. (The downside is the inability to do "join-type" queries).

Comment: @Thilo ok changed the structure of `visits` to use arrays instead of hashes in order for `$unwind` to work. Seems ok, but now I am missing a condition to filter out `minutes` greater than 12. See my edit above. Any help on this will be great

Comment: Now you should be able to add another $match at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $match pipeline element you use at the beginning can be used multiple times, including after your $unwind step.

Once $unwind splits your visits array elements each into its own document you can add {$match:{"visits.minute":{$gt:12}}} to the end of your pipeline and that should leave only visits you want.